# Transfer sound with my powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

So we have a PowerPoint to present. I made the PowerPoint on one computer and it had different sounds. Well we emailed the PowerPoint to others and they got it but it did not transfer the sounds. We need the PowerPoint on another computer to present it but we need the sound too. What should we do??

Comment: manage to get your PowerPoint presentation document and the sound effects file under the same folder structure and hyperlink the same audio files in the local structure and then, like uniquerockrz writes in his answer below, you can get the structure compressed to an archive file.. (you can check for the media files in Window system drive's `Program Files\Microsoft Office`, `Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\MEDIA` or other media folders)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Zip the sound and powerpoint files and send the zipped file as a whole